# WebAssembly + concurrency: trying to set a thread-local stack from C/C++

Tags: c++, c, clang, webassembly

I have a re-entrant C++ function whose `wasm` output is not "thread-safe" when using imported shared memory, because the function makes use of an aliased stack that lives on the shared linear memory on a hardcoded position.

I'm aware that multithreading is not fully supported yet, and if I want to use multiple instances of the same module concurrently, avoiding crashing and data races it's my responsibility, but I accept the challenge.

My X problem is: My code is not thread-safe, and I need it to be by having non-overlapping stacks.

My Y problem is: I'm trying to modify the `__stack_pointer` so I can implement the stack separation, but it doesn't compile. I have tried with `extern unsigned char __stack_pointer;` but it throws me the following error:

```
wasm-ld: error: symbol type mismatch: __stack_pointer
>>> defined as WASM_SYMBOL_TYPE_GLOBAL in <internal>
>>> defined as WASM_SYMBOL_TYPE_DATA in senseless.o
```

Since maybe I'm not supposed to touch that pointer directly, I'm thinking on other solutions as well (see below).

Working example:

```
#define WASM_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default"))) extern "C"
#define WASM_IMPORT extern "C"

struct senseless
{
    unsigned c[1024];
    unsigned __attribute__((noinline)) compute(unsigned seed) { return c[seed % 1024]; }
};

WASM_EXPORT unsigned compute_senseless(unsigned seed)
{
    senseless h;
    h.c[5] = seed;
    return h.compute(seed);
}
```

After compilation, the resultant implementation in WAST is:

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "memory" (memory (;0;) 2 2 shared))
  
  (func (;0;) (type 0) (param i32) (result i32)
    (local i32)                          ; int l; // address of h
    (global.set 0                        ; SP = l (4096 = sizeof(senseless))
      (local.tee 1                           ; where l = SP - 4096
        (i32.sub (global.get 0)
                 (i32.const 4096))))
    (i32.store offset=20                 ; linear_memory[l + 5 * 4] = seed
      (local.get 1) (local.set 0))
    (i32.load                            ; return_value = linear_memory[l + (seed & 1023) * 4]
      (i32.add (local.get 1)
               (i32.shl                  
                  (i32.and (local.get 0) (i32.const 1023))
                  (i32.const 2))))
    (global.set 0                        ; SP = l + 4096
      (i32.add (local.get 1) (i32.const 4096))))
        
  (global (;0;) (mut i32) (i32.const 66576)) ; SP = 66576 (stack pointer)
  (export "compute_senseless" (func 0)))
```

So the function first decreases SP in 4096 bytes to allocate `h`, execute `h.c[5] = seed`, push `h.c[seed % 2014]` on the (wasm) stack, and then restore the SP.

If two instances of this module are working in parallel on two different WebWorkers, `h.c[5] = seed` could cause a data race, because they use the same hard-coded SP as stack base.

To force each instance having it's own non-overlapping region for the stack, I need to modify the stack pointer, but I don't know how to do it. I have some ideas though (using `wasi-libc` or `emscripten` is overkilling to me):

1. As I said at the beginning: modifying the `__stack_pointer`; but I can't make it happen (the error is shown above). Besides, I don't know if I have anything else to consider besides making it 16-byte aligned.
2. Clang already defines the function `__wasm_init_tls`, but its function body is empty and no one calls it (the symbol pops up when using the `--export-all` flag). I don't know if that function is usable anyhow.
3. I'm aware that clang has support for relocation sections, dynamic linking, etc, but I don't know how to play with all of these options either to achieve my purpose. I don't understand these options good enough.
4. Or... doing it by hand with a WAST function that sets the pointer and that I have to call manually just after instantiation:

```
// C++
void place_SP(int addr); // Implemented in WAST.

/* To be called from javascript; I'll make sure that this call never happens concurrently, that SP is multiple of 16 (stack base is 16-byte aligned), and that I have space enough to avoid stack overlapping. */
WASM_EXPORT void init_stack(int SP) { place_SP(SP); }

// place_SP.wast
(func $place_SP (param $addr i32)
      (global.set 0 (local.get $addr)))
```

but I'm unsure about what else do I need to write on `place_SP.wast` (is it a different module? should I need to specify a `(type)` entry?), and how should I modify my `makefile` to properly compile `place_SP.wast` and link it with `senseless.o` to produce a valid `senseless.wasm`.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .wasm

WASI_SDK := <my-wasi-sdk-path> # I'm using wasi-sdk 12.
CXX := $(WASI_SDK)/bin/clang++
LD := $(WASI_SDK)/bin/wasm-ld

CPPFLAGS := --sysroot=$(WASI_SDK)/share/wasi-sysroot
CXXFLAGS := -O3 -flto -fno-exceptions
LDFLAGS := --lto-O3 -E --no-entry --import-memory --max-memory=131072 \
       --features=atomics,bulk-memory --shared-memory

senseless.wasm: senseless.o
    $(LD) --verbose $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    wasm-opt $@ -Oz -o $@
    wasm-strip $@
    wasm2wat -f --enable-threads --enable-bulk-memory $@ > $*.wast

senseless.o: senseless.cpp
    $(CXX) -v -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) senseless.wasm senseless.o
```

Compiler logging output (only what I consider to be the relevant stuff):

```
# Internal compiler call (I have omitted options regarding paths):
 "<wasi-sdk>/bin/clang-11" -cc1 -triple wasm32-unknown-wasi -emit-llvm-bc -flto -flto-unit -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name senseless.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=none -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu generic -fvisibility hidden -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -O3 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o senseless.o -x c++ senseless.cpp

# Memory layout (linker output)
wasm-ld: mem: global base = 1024 # I wonder what are the first 1024 bytes used for.
wasm-ld: mem: __wasm_init_memory_flag offset=1024     size=4        align=4
wasm-ld: mem: static data = 4 # No .rodata/.bss in this example, only the (unused) i32 flag.
wasm-ld: mem: stack size  = 65536 # One page (64KiB) for the stack, from 66576 to 1040.
wasm-ld: mem: stack base  = 1040 # I wonder what are the bytes from 1028 to 1039 used for.
wasm-ld: mem: stack top   = 66576
wasm-ld: mem: heap base   = 66576 # Heap from 66576 up to 131072.
wasm-ld: mem: total pages = 2
wasm-ld: mem: max pages   = 2
```

**NOTE:** I have tried to personalize the stack size by adding `-z,stack-size=131072` to `LDFLAGS`, so the stack size is two pages long instead of one for example (and increasing `--max-memory` to three pages), but none of stack base/size/top change at all.

## SOLUTION

I made it work based on the selected answer. I added a file called `stack-trick.S` (the `.hidden` construct is to avoid `place_SP` is exported, which is the default):

```
.globl place_SP
.hidden place_SP
.globaltype __stack_pointer, i32

place_SP:
   .functype place_SP(i32) -> ()
   local.set 0
   global.set __stack_pointer
   end_function
```

Now, in my `senseless.cpp` code, I added:

```
extern "C" void place_SP(int);

WASM_EXPORT void init_stack(/* some args */)
{
     int SP = /* some computation based on parameters */;
     place_SP(SP);
}
```

and in the makefile, I added:

```
senseless.wasm: stack-trick.o

stack-trick.o: stack-trick.S
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

and `senseless.wast` now have a fancy new exported function (`init_stack`) where, in addition, the call to `place_SP` has been inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are doing multi-threading with emscripten then each thread will already have its own stack and its own value for `__stack_pointer`.  Thats is part of what defines a thread.

If you still want to manipulate the stack yourself (perhaps to have many stacks within a single thread) then you can use the emscripten helper functions `stackSave` (to get the SP of the current thread) and `stackRestore`  (to set the SP of the current thread).

If you are not using emscripten at all, then you are in uncharted territory (what runtime are using using?  how are you starting new threads?), but the simplest way to do stack pointer manipulation would be with assembly code.  See how emscripten implements these functions:

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/system/lib/compiler-rt/stack_ops.S

So you could do something like this:

```
.globaltype __stack_pointer, i32

place_SP:
  .functype place_SP(i32) -> ()
  local.get 0
  global.set __stack_pointer
  end_function
```

Then compile that code with `clang -c splace_sp.s -o place_sp.o`

Comment: My runtime is the web browser, and I'm not launching new threads, but javascript workers, so they are acting more like multiple processes sharing memory than threads. I will try the assembly thing.

Comment: Magically, it compiles, but! the `place_SP` function seems to dissapear. `place_sp.o` contains the symbol but the `.wast` output don't. I have tried to force the symbol to be exported with `WASM_EXPORT void place_SP(int)` in my `.cpp` and call it from `compute_senseless`, but then the linker says: `undefined symbol: place_SP`. And adding `--export=place_SP` to `LDFLAGS` didn't work either (it says the `place_SP` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

__stack_pointer is a built-in, we can use this neat trick. Just export it and make sure to only access it from the JS side.

```
void set_sp(void* sp){
    __asm__(
        "local.get 0\n"
        "global.set __stack_pointer\n"
    );
}
```

The asm files are great for declaring your own new globals, given that Clang does not support defining wasm globals yet. In cases like this I'd opt for inline wat.